# Attention heads "competence" in NLP transformer networks

Tags: nlp, huggingface-transformers, attention-model

I am currently writing my masters' thesis on transformers in NLP. I have been reading a lot and have been wondering about one fact for a while. In transformers, we have self-attention and attention heads. Say I have word embeddings of 512 dimensions and 8 heads, then every head will deal with 64 dimensions of every input word to calculate self-attention.

Here is a picture from a textbook that might illustrate what I mean:

[image]

Here is my question now. Could we say that every attention-head has a sort of "competence" for a part-meaning of the words? Say the first 64 dimensions of a word embeddings always deal with the words' emotionality; would the first head then be the emotionality-head? And what would that mean for interpretability and the learning in the network?

This is my first question here; I hope to have expressed myself clear enough.

Thank you for any answers!

Comment: I think you want to have a look at this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.02679) section `attention-head view`.

Answer (score 1):

A attention head would calculate the attention scores for every token pair, based on their "relevance". The more relevant the pair is, the higher the score would be. More heads would just allow the model to learn more representation of "relevance".

You might have understood the attention head wrong. The head has a dimension of (512, 64) does not mean that it would only take care of the first 64 dimensions of the word embedding. Instead, it is projecting all 512 dimensions of the word embedding to a 64 dimension space. As a result, all dimensions of the word embedding would be taken care of in every head's calculation.

There is a paper that studies every head focuses on in GPT2. You can have a look. https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.04284